# Extract continuous siblings in XSL

Tags: html, xslt, siblings

I have an HTML file like this:

```
<root>
    <br>
    <h3>The first H3 text</h3><br>
    <p>para1 content in first H3</p><br>
    <p>para2 content in first H3</p><br>
    <h3>The second H3 text</h3><br>
    <p>para1 content in second H3</p><br>
    <p>para2 content in second H3</p><br>
    <p>para3 content in second H3</p><br>
    <p>para4 content in second H3</p><br>
</root>
```

I want to write an XSL which gives output like this one:

```
<sec>
    <br />
    <secHead>The first H3 text</secHead><br />
    <para>para1 content in first H3</para><br />
    <para>para2 content in first H3</para><br />
</sec>
<br />
<sec>
    <br/>
    <secHead>The second H3 text</secHead><br/>
    <para>para1 content in second H3</para><br/>
    <para>para2 content in second H3</para><br/>
    <para>para3 content in second H3</para><br/>
    <para>para4 content in second H3</para><br/>
</sec>
```

How can we get this output writing XSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, +1.

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="*[not(self::h3)]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h3[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="h3"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="h3">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
     <br />
    </xsl:if>
     <sec>
      <br />
      <secHead><xsl:value-of select="."/></secHead>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
     </sec>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided source** (the html must be converted to wellformed XML!!!):

```
<root>
    <br/>
    <h3>The first H3 text</h3><br/>
    <p>para1 content in first H3</p><br/>
    <p>para2 content in first H3</p><br/>
    <h3>The second H3 text</h3><br/>
    <p>para1 content in second H3</p><br/>
    <p>para2 content in second H3</p><br/>
    <p>para3 content in second H3</p><br/>
    <p>para4 content in second H3</p><br/>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<sec>
   <br/>
   <secHead>The first H3 text</secHead>
   <br/>
   <p>para1 content in first H3</p>
   <br/>
   <p>para2 content in first H3</p>
   <br/>
</sec>
<br/>
<sec>
   <br/>
   <secHead>The second H3 text</secHead>
   <br/>
   <p>para1 content in second H3</p>
   <br/>
   <p>para2 content in second H3</p>
   <br/>
   <p>para3 content in second H3</p>
   <br/>
   <p>para4 content in second H3</p>
   <br/>
</sec>
```

**Explanation**:

The key point in this solution is that we define an `xsl:key` that captures the relation between an `h3` element and all its immediate following siblings elements (such that they aren't `h3` themselves and this `h3` is their first `h3` preceding sibling).